# Storing mongoDB on phone without cellular/wifi connection

Tags: meteor

I need to store information in the mongoDB database on the phone to be used while off-line. The app will download the data while online, and store it in the DB, to be used while off-line. Then when the user is online again, I will send the mongoDB info collected, using my API.

I don't want the mongoDB to be synced with the server while online, either. I want to keep the data on the individual phone. I want to use the data in mongoDB while offline. I need the app to be able to quit/restart, without losing the data on the phone locally.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db

Comment: it says, "GroundDB is a caching only storage - meaning it does not support resuming of method calls/cross tab updates etc." What does this mean? Can the app be quit and opened again, and keep the data? What is resuming a method call? What is a cross-tab update?

Comment: It's like: `if you were calling a method and your apps goes down, our system doesn't handles that and you should implement the logic for that cases....we only support offline functionality of your app`...that is in human language :)

Comment: Can the app be quit and opened again and retain the data?

Comment: Typo `and your apps goes down` should be `and your phone network goes down`

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to consider.

1) Create a local mongo database - this is client only storage with no server publication (not sure if it persists between app invocations)

2) sqlite can do the job, but only on Android (not IOS)

3) LokiJS is a fast JS only database that promises to be useful - haven't explored it, but it would be good to hear some feedback

4) If the data is small, you could use LocalStorage, it's pretty simple, you just need to look after serialising and de-serialising it yourself